# iPhone - Execute iphone app from documents folder

Tags: iphone, bash, scripting, binary

I'm writing an app which must download other apps and EXECUTE them from the documents folder.
One of the approaches I was thinking about is to use a bash script like the one in installous which unzips the app and copies whatever whenever it's needed.That way I can install it,but not execute it.

So I was wondering if there is a way to just unzip it and run it from within the documents folder.I am using a jailbroken device so the roo access is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a jailbroken phone, but maybe [`open -a ...`](http://ss64.com/osx/open.html) would work?